# why std::bind will copy twice when pass by value?

Tags: c++11, templates, std-function, stdbind

Here is the sample code

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int a{ 3 };
    A() { std::cout << "con\n"; };
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "con2\n"; };
};


int main()
{
    std::function<void(A)> f = [](A a) {};
    A data;
    auto p = std::bind(f,data);
    p();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
con
con2
con2
con2
```

I knew that the cause of the first three line output

1. create the data object
2. capture it as a member of object p
3. pass the A object by value

but why it calls the constructor again?
BTW, the g++ and vc++ share the same behavior

Comment: First you create an A, then you copy it to std::bind.  Then std::bind copies it to std::function and then std::function copies it to the lambda.  If you change the code to `void (*f)(A a) = [](A a) {};` you elimiate the std::function and remove one of the copies.

Comment: The other thing is using either of `void (*f)(const A & a) = [](const A & a) {};` or `std::function<void(const A &)> f = [](const A & a) {};` gets rid of copies (but you still get one from std::bind)

Comment: I add a breakpoint before run `p()`, it only shows the first two line, after finishing `p()`, it prints the last two line. it seems that the std::bind is passed by reference.

Comment: Bind has to make a copy of A in case the variable goes out of scope before the bind is called.  Have a look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/Skmdv9vgO for your 'std::function by value' case.  And this: https://onlinegdb.com/BJ92DcwlO for a 'function pointer by value' case.  And this: https://onlinegdb.com/B1_WuqPld for a 'std::function by reference' case.

Comment: So, when the std::function is called, the bind object copies its A into the std::function and the std::function copies it into the lambda.